# Getting console.log output from Chrome with Selenium python only once and after call second time empty

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

console.log of chrome is not working when i call once again

```
with open("logs.txt", "a+") as fd:
    for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
        print "Login logs:", entry
        log = entry
        if log['source'] == 'network':
            fileData["logError"] = log['message']
    fd.write(json.dumps(fileData))
    fd.write("\n")
```

web driver of chrome

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to go back to the top of the file:

```
file.seek(0)
```

Comment: driver.get_log('browser') used for getting info from console.log lines from web driver that get empty once i try again !

Comment: @user2750084 I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment

Comment: In web driver in selenium python i use above code to fetch potential error that occur in console in browser and it works too but problem is Reusing same code after automate browse to another page i get empty

Comment: @user2750084 so did you try adding the command I suggested at the end of your `for` loop?

Comment: `with open("logs.txt", "a+") as fd:
        for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
            log = entry
            print entry
            print "\n"
            if log['source'] == 'network':
                fileData["logError"] = log['message']
            if log['source'] == 'javascript':
                fileData["logError"] = log['message']
            fd.seek(0)
        fd.write(json.dumps(fileData))
        fd.write("\n")`

Comment: above code i try but same console logs are not recording twice